# Why is User.Identity null after login with AspNet.Identity 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, dnx

I am using Microsofts AspNet.Identity 3.0 framework within the DNX RC1. With the help of some tutorials I have built a custom authentication system. After a successful password check some claims are created for the user and the Authentication will be set:

```
var claimsPrincipal = await SignInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
if (claimsPrincipal != null && claimsPrincipal.Identity != null)
{
    // Set the claims to the user 
    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "App");
}
```

After this login action my browser has two cookies: *.AspNet.Cookies* and *.AspNet.Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application*

However I do have now a problem with my identity. Controllers annotated with [Authorize] are not executed at all. And controllers with [AllowAnonymous] give me a NullReferenceException because User.Identity is null:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/trips")]
public class TripController : Controller
{

[HttpGet("")]
public JsonResult Get()
{
    var trips = _repository.GetUserTripsWithStops(User.Identity.Name);
    ...

    return Json(results);
}
```

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my authentication?

As I guess that my mistake is somewhere in the Startup.cs file - here is the configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseIdentity();
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/App/Login");
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
            defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index" });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank god I have found the solution after more than one day trial and error. Finally I just added the AutomaticAuthenticate-line in the Startup.cs file:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/App/Login");
});
```

Comment: You should add below line in startup.cs inside Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) method.

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseCookieAuthentication() is obselete in latest version.

Answer (score 2):

In order to access the `User` object, the controller/action must be decorated with `[Authorize]`. `[AllowAnonymous]` is only useful in conjunction with `[Authorize]`. On its own it does nothing, as by default, everything is accessible to anonymous users.

Comment: You are right, that the User object actually only makes sense within an [Authorize] block. However these blocks are then not executed at all - therefore I changed for testing the Authorize to AllowAnonymous. With the use of AllowAnonymous I have discovered that User.Identity is NOT null when I am not logged in (deleted all cookies) - but as soon as I have logged in, the User.Identity is null. Actually I would have expected this behaviour the other way round.

Comment: I am getting null on User as ClaimsPrincipal. I tried everything adding Authorize / AllowAnonymous on method / controller